# How do I create a custom server with a custom map?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I recently got into fooling around on mg_ servers, which are basically servers whose maps are "mg"s, mini games.  These minigames range around actual parkour, to deathrun, bunnyhopping maps, obstacle courses, etc.

Of course, I'd love to be able to play these maps by myself, but it doesn't seem like I can actually start a custom server with a custom map; it seems I'm restricted to Valve's official maps.

How do I play on a custom map? I'd like it so I can play offline if I need to, or online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open console and type

```
map mapname
```

ie:

```
map de_dust2
```

Since bunnyhopping has been completely ruined in CS:GO I imagine these servers use custom settings to get rid of the limitations, so you'll have to find those, use sv_cheats 1 and then change the settings.

Comment: Quick question, is there any way to view what maps you have without having to open up any folders (as in, can you see what maps you have while in-game)?

Comment: @Retrosaur maps or maplist in console I think. Also map, space, down arrow.